# What do I do about my abusive father?

Tags: teen, parents, abuse

I'm 16 years old and live in the UK. My father has been physically and verbally abusing me for as long as I could remember, e. g. he punches, hits or slaps me. It's only been reported once to the police but in reality it's been happening all my life.

He abuses me, my mother and my sister. My mum is always too afraid to report it to the police. Growing from an Asian family it's hard for parents to show affection for their children and they are extremely strict, but the violence is unnecessary.

I found my father beating up my mother in the morning, it's what woke me up. This was reported to the police because I urged my mother, but because they couldn't find any bruises they're not taking immediate action. I hate talking to the police and am petrified of them.

As my father owns the house he can stay for as long as he pleases, until the police come to interview him. He's been staying for almost three days and I've been too scared to see him so I stayed with my cousins.

Today I wanted to come home so I could do all my schoolwork that is on my computer at home, but I found out my father was still home. I called my mum and asked if she could ask him to leave as I am scared and feel unsafe being alone with him in the house. Instead, she screamed at me and said "there's nothing she can do?".  Is it really my fault that I don't want to be alone with my abusive father? This really frustrates me about my mother and it drives me insane.

I really really don't know what to do but my schoolwork is so important to me. I just cannot stand the abuse from my father anymore, when all of this happens the part that I hate the most is that I feel bad for him. He has never done anything in my life but leave bruises on my skin. But I still feel bad for him and hate myself so much for it.

Comment: Well the answer kind of depends on your age somewhat. If you are 18 or older then for your own self, you can of course just move out. If you are younger than 18 then unfortunately there is nothing you alone can do. You can (as it sounds like they have been already) involve the police. They generally need "proof" that is solid enough to hold up in a court that such abuse is taking place so you can try to record it. Make sure you have a solid case that someone can't argue against before you call them. If the police are difficult for you to talk to then social services might be easier possibly

Comment: Welcome to Parenting. I've given your post some much needed grammar/layout upgrades. Sorry that you're in this situation. Note that if you have (regular) bruises from abuse, you shouldn't have a hard time convincing the police to come check it out. For completeness' sake, where do you live? It also makes a difference.

Comment: I'm so sorry to hear this is happening to you. Your mother is unfortunately probably too scared to help you, especially if she is also being abused. Do you have access to a counselor or therapist, perhaps through your school?

Comment: Admitting you're a victim is the first step to getting help for yourself and others.  StackExchange is a global community and to help you get the right kind of help can you tell us what kind of abuse you're facing and what country/state you're in?

Comment: Thank you for your responses, i'm only 16 and I live in the U.K. The school I go to is difficult to get help and we don't have a therapist but i'm considering going to councilling soon. I've been physically abused most my life, he would punch, hit, slap etc me. I really appreciate the responses.

Comment: I totally feel for you as this was my life as a child. I live near an asian-rich city, and work with a lot of asian folks and what I hear at work as chatter agrees with the culture of silence that you mention.Try calling Childline? they've seen it all before and can advise. I can tell you from my own experience that your mum is going to have to be very brave. My own mum was not. The culture back then was not unlike what you describe.

Comment: just remember that you are a victim, not a perpetrator. With a manipulative or violent parent (both mine had both traits), its very easy to get sucked in to their way of seeing things. Remember that they have to justify it to themselves somehow.

Answer (score 5):

Call Social Services.  Tell them what you told us and they will start an investigation.  Despite how they are portrayed on TV, they don't often remove children from a home without first trying to work with the parents to correct the situation.  I'm so sorry you have to live through this, no one should have to live through this.  If I knew the names of your parents and where you lived, I'd call Social Services myself.

Hang in there.

Comment: if he ends up reliving with us i'll call the social services myself because i can't stand being around him any longer, thank you for taking the time to respond to this and i will definitely take your advice if nothing else is done about it. many thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: THIS.  Keep reporting it until something is done.

Answer (score 4):

I really feel sorry for your situation, at 16 you should be being a kid, hanging out with your friends and not have anything more than maybe a bit of acne and school to worry about.  Unfortunately some adults do horrible things even when you love them, and ultimately that's why you feel bad for him.  You do have lots of options open to you.

I would urge you to adopt a 'mindfulness' approach to the situation and bear in mind that you are only in control of your actions.  You cannot force your mother to leave, report other assaults, or to press charges.  Equally you cannot force your father to change his ways.  If you want him to stop assaulting you (and others) then you need to act, and well done for the actions you've taken so far.

At school, your teachers all have a 'duty of care', if you're having a problem at home they are all trained in child protection and reporting and they know who to speak to and what to do.  You do not have to seek out one person like a school counsellor, and you can just pick any teacher that you feel you can trust - explain your situation to them and let them take notes.

The fact that you have run away from home (even if to another family member) is very significant, a teacher may arrange for you to meet someone from Social Services, as much as you may have heard bad things about them, their job is to stop people like you from being harmed.  They can do this in school time and without your parents knowing if you feel you or your sister might be in danger for reporting them.

If you're finding it difficult to start the conversation with a teacher (and I can fully understand that) then start out by asking their advice on bullying, they'll ask you some questions about who and what's happening.

If you feel that you really cannot trust your teachers then there are a number of services where you can get help.

- **Childline** on `0800 1111` at any time (24 hours) or  https://www.childline.org.uk/get-support/contacting-childline/
- **NSPCC** on `0808 800 5000` or https://www.nspcc.org.uk/what-you-can-do/report-abuse/

The childline number is completely free, does not show up on the phone bill on most networks and it doesn't use up credit on your mobile if you have one, you can even call if you have no credit, and have a [confidentiality promise](https://www.childline.org.uk/about/confidentiality-promise/) that they won't tell anyone else about your situation unless you ask them to, with a few exceptions.

If you have any evidence (photographs of bruises, mobile phone footage of assaults and the like) of assaults on anyone in your home then you can contact the police or social services directly, each local authority has a safeguarding number .  Evidence can also take the form of a log or diary, write & date incidents as they occur and give as much detail as you can - insults he uses as well as the physical details (for example where/how he hurts people, where it happened, and if things got broken).  Even if the police do nothing *this time*, it all gets filed away in evidence and over time builds a strong case.

While someone is being assaulted, and if you can, dial `999` on your landline phone and just leave the line open - the operator will know your address from the caller-id and will send the police.  All `999` calls are recorded and can be used as evidence by the police to press charges even if your mother decides not to - if they get lots of calls about one person's behaviour they may choose to do this.

You should not worry about your father "owning the house", that doesn't mean he can't be made to leave.  Social Services and the Police most definitely can make sure that happens if they believe you or your sister are at-risk.

I'm sure there's a lot I've missed here - but the childline website has lots of great resources on this.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This by far has helped me so much in my current situation, this has made me consider talking to my school which I will do. Many family members have been witnesses of the abuse so would asking them to contact the police be able to help in anyway. I'll check the website out now and I am really really grateful for your response, thank you so much.

Comment: You're very welcome, certainly if the police decided to take action (or if you decided to speak to social services) then any evidence that they can provide would always be important and taken into consideration.

Comment: dear s.anon, I posted a little above about CHildline but what I have to say fits better here.If you're not careful for yourself and your siblings, then either history could repeat for them in later life, or you could experience difficulties in future relationships, or in your relations with your own future children. My mother was *not brave*, and abandoned us. I'm still, at nearly 50, dealing with the emotinal fallout of not dealing with it then or soon after. If you are offered counselling in any form, take it.Getting these images into a compartment is better than blaming yourself.

Comment: "You should not worry about your father "owning the house", that doesn't mean he can't be made to leave" very true Your mother has a legal claim as his spouse.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that no one should have to deal with that. I myself have had to deal with my father slightly my mother yelling at me severely and that just by itself. But your case is both and I believe that you should try and call your local social services to ask for next steps so that you wont have to deal with this abuse anymore for your sake and as it appears also your mothers sake.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you had to go through that and I hope you're doing better now, as to now the police are making him stay without contact to myself , mother and sister for a month until then they will decide what's happening. If he ends up coming back i'm certain to call social services as I can no longer stand him anymore. Thank you for your response